# Section without enumeration

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, numbering

I declare sections without numbering by typing section *, but a number is displayed according to the level, as shown in the figure.
I want sections declared with section * to have no number
here is the current code.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{22mm}{14mm}{12mm}{25mm}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{white}}%
{}{0em}{\colorbox{RoyalBlue!90}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesection\enspace #1}}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{white}}%
{}{0em}{\colorbox{RoyalBlue!30}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\thesubsection\enspace #1}}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\sffamily\large\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}{\thesubsubsection\enspace #1}{1em}{}[{\color{black}\titlerule[1.5pt]}]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapitre 1}
\section*{section without numerotation }
\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\section{section without numerotation''}
\end{document}
```

And this what i get when generate a pdf file .

[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: In some way off topic. But I think that you have a misconception about `\section{...}` and `\section*{...}`. The latter isn't simply a _section without numbering_. It's more correct to say that it is a section that doesn't increment the counter of sections. Of course, usually you display a `\section*{...}` but if what you really want is to don't display numbering you should follow other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[block]{\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{white}}%
{}{0em}{\colorbox{RoyalBlue!90}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}
```